# MySQL - Update with COUNT, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to update a MySQL table to show column name 'processed' as '2' if there is duplicate entries for 'name' and 'address_1', but it's not working - as usual I think I'm just being a bit of a moron..

Here's what I'm trying

```
UPDATE `records`
SET `processed`='2', `count` = (SELECT COUNT(`user`)
FROM `records`
WHERE `name`<>''
AND `address_1`<>'')
WHERE `count`=> '1';
```

Basically, if there's more than one 'name' and 'address_1' then the 'processed' field needs updating to '2'..

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Comment: One of the features of database normalization is to not store calculated values.  Think about dropping the count field from the records table.

Comment: @AndyLester Cheers for that! I always wondered..but always put them in just in case - should speed things up now! :)

Comment: Superstition is no basis for programming habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this one to return duplicated names and addresses:

```
SELECT name, address_1, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM records
GROUP BY name, address_1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

and then join this query to the records table, and update the column processed to 2 where the join succeeds:

```
UPDATE
  records INNER JOIN (SELECT name, address_1, COUNT(*) cnt
                      FROM records
                      GROUP BY name, address_1
                      HAVING COUNT(*)>1) duplicates
  ON records.name = duplicates.name
     AND records.address_1=duplicates.address_1
SET
  `processed`='2',
  `count` = duplicates.cnt
WHERE 
  records.`name`<>''
  AND records.`address_1`<>''
```

Comment: It's coming up with an odd error `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous` Not seen this one before..

Comment: @ElliotReed yes, both records and duplicates have the same columns name and address_1, so on the where clause we need to specify the table name.... it should be fixed now...

Comment: Ah excellent! I just googled it and got the same :) Thank you so much for this, very very useful!